# Local storage on new window

Tags: javascript, local-storage, window.open

I am using `Local Storage` to save a few string values, in my application. I want to save the values of different users separately. The issue is that my local storage object is updating keys and values of the same object.

For instance, there are two users A and B. The goal is have local storage object for both users separately.

Suppose, `Local storage` object's key for A is `Alog` and `Blog` for B. When I login user A first, the object contains values for key `Alog`.

After that user B logins then `Alog` will be replaced by `Blog`. Whereas I want to retain both of them.

```
localStorage.setItem(user_logs, logs);
window.open("/newpage","_self");
```

`user_logs` is dynamically created string which contains username appended with the word `log`. So if user is A then `user_log` value would be `Alog`.

Can you please identify what needs to be done, where I am making a mistake?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Mitya, I have added code upon your suggestion.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, I understand your point. But my requirement is to save values for both users, can this be achieved?

Comment: Then you will need to design your local storage schema such that it can handle multiple users using the same device. Perhaps have an outer object, with a key for each user, and inside that object is that user's versions of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this problem will solve by using incognito windows or using 2 different browsers.

Comment: @Badar this is not a problem, local storage is shared between normal pages and if you want to test your application locally, you need to do this with 2 different browsers or use incognito mode to prevent the local storage from being shared.